# In Emacs how can I find where the input-method "german-prefix" is defined?

Tags: emacs, internationalization, elisp, lookup

Emacs provides the input method "`german-prefix`" (It helps to type the character "ä" as `"a`). In order to create a customised version of this input-method I would like to find the place where in the Emacs Lisp source files this input-method is defined.

I've searched for the string "german-prefix" in all Emacs Lisp file directories, but without success. I tried quite a few other searches, but remained unsuccessful.

Where is this input-method defined? And is there possibly a generic way to *lookup* the Elisp file an input-method is defined in (similar to what `find-function` does for functions)?

Comment: After having checked the answers  I realised, that I had not searched in the correct directories: I looked only under the `lisp` directory, beacuse I wasn't aware that the `leim` directory contains lisp files (and many of them!) as well...

Comment: Very good point indeed.  According to Emacs scriptures, `M-x describe-input-method` *should* come with a button that lets you see the source.  But somehow this was never implemented.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` requesting this new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've found my way to `input-method-alist`:

1. <kbd>f1 f C-\</kbd>
2. jump to definition of `toggle-input-method`
3. jump to definition of `read-input-method-name`
4. see `input-method-alist`.

The relevant bit in that list is now `quail-use-package`.
Now using `edebug-defun` on it <kbd>C-u C-M-x</kbd>,
I see that it's indeed `latin-pre.el`.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in the file `leim/quail/latin-pre.el`. There is no functionality for mapping an input method to the place where it is defined, but currently (emacs 24.2) all the input methods seem to be defined in `leim/quail/*.el`.